# Map signal to a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, signal-processing

I am not sure if it makes any sense, that is why I am asking.

I have 500 samples of an electric signal I want to analyze, and during class, someone proposed mapping it to a square matrix could be a way to study it. But I have not found a single paper os book chapter where something similar is done.

The idea is to take groups of samples and stack them to form a square matrix. I understood matrices as linear transformations, so, I do not understand what meaning could this idea have.

What do you think? If this does not make sense at all, is there any way to map a time series into a square signal that makes sense?

Comment: What exactly about the signal do you wish to study? I too haven't really heard of this idea; usually a discretely sampled signal is represented as a vector. Often times, you might want to calculate the discrete Fourier transform of the signal for a frequency analysis (to do so would require multiplying the sample vector by a square matrix).

Comment: In the treatment of discrete-time LTI systems, it is very common to associate with the time series $x(1),x(2),\dots,x(T)$ the Hankel matrix
$$
\pmatrix{x(1) & x(2) & \cdots & x(T - L + 1)\\
x(2) & x(3) & \cdots & x(T - L + 2)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
x(L) & x(L+1) & \cdots & x(T)}.
$$

Comment: In general, this is not a common tool. However, there may be cases where this makes sense. It just all depends on what you are trying to do.